# how to use one background for a tiled/mosaic div layout in css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, jquery-masonry, tile

Using css or jquery, how do i create something like the attached that is responsive.

[image]

I have the grid and all. It's simpler than the photo i attached. Just a 7x5 grid. I just don't know how to create a background image that will span all the divs in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 images one with grid only which should be transparent and another is your photo or anything. With CSS you can overlap both images with position:absolute and z-index.

Try below code:

HTML:

```
<div class="img_container">
<img src=1.jpg/>
<img class="grid" src=2.jpg/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img_container{
  position:relative;
}
.img_container img{
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
.img_container img.grid{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
  opacity:0.5; //Remove it if you don't need to make transparent.
}
```

And you need to make both images in same size.
Here is example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iGIyEqu/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to place the background in the grid container.

My solution, using a table (that I think that is also the easy way to do the grid). But the background in the container solution is also useful for other grid approaches.

HTML

```
<table class="container">
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td colspan="2">3</td>
  <td rowspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td rowspan="2">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td rowspan="2">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td colspan="2">3</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    width: 99%;
    height: 99%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/400/300");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: solid white 8px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/77MuS/)